# Use webassembly (.wasm) within a Dart library

Tags: dart, webassembly

I compiled a wasm flie using Rust. I can load it into JavaScript without issue, however I can't find ANY docs on how to use that same wasm file in Dart directly.

The goal would be something like:

```dart
import 'cool_wasm.wasm' as wasmModule;
myLib = await wasmModule; \\let wasm compile
myLib.some_function(1,2)
```

Comment: Currently that is not possible. You have to do the loading through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, you can load WebAssembly in Dart via the JavaScript interop package. [Here](https://creativebracket.com/how-to-load-a-webassembly-file-in-dart-for-web/) is an article outlining how to do it.